# BigSur: at: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, at

How would I fix this on macOS 11

```
$ at 0200
at: cannot open lockfile /usr/lib/cron/jobs/.lockfile: Operation not permitted
```

This started to happen after accidentally dismissing an
incessant prompt whether I'd give Terminal permissions to
administer the system.

This goes away after 5-10 minutes: retrying at command succeeds

Removing the lock file did not help the matter:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/cron/jobs/.lockfile
rm: /usr/lib/cron/jobs/.lockfile: No such file or directory
antonsmbp:tangomultic atropashko$ at 0300
at: cannot open lockfile /usr/lib/cron/jobs/.lockfile: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ls -l /usr/lib/cron/jobs/.lockfile to see if lockfile exists longer than necessary.
Maybe its owned by root or other user and coannot be created as your user.

Try to remove /usr/lib/cron/jobs/.lockfile as root (you have to enable root).

Comment: You don't ever have to enable root on Mac - nor, if you did, would it gain you anything.

Comment: Removed: no dice.